# object contains property but get undefined when call the property

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the `JobService` which includes some method to get `Job`. At same time i have some related component which the components has to take eligible data for itself. When `JobService` created i get one job  and save it inside the `service`. So when i want to take the job title from inside `JobService` i encountered `undefined` data. Which the data has taken from `Web Api`. Here's the `Service`.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class JobService {
  jobUrl = "http://localhost:5000/api/Job";
  job: Job;

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {
        this.getJob(1).subscribe(x => this.job = x)
  }



  getJob(id: number): Observable<Job> {
    return this.httpClient.get<Job>(this.jobUrl + '/' + id);
  }

  getJobTitle() {

    //job object appears in jobservice object. It has initialized.
    console.log(this);

    //the object return undefined. Which service containing the job
    console.log(this.job);
    // setTimeout(() => console.log(this.job), 300);

    //also this is return undefined
    return this.job.title;
  }
```

So here's the `JobDetailsComponent`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-jobdetails',
  templateUrl: './jobdetails.component.html',
})
export class JobdetailsComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private jobService: JobService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
      this.jobTitle = this.jobService.getJobTitle();
  }

  jobTitle: string;

}
```

How can i solve this problem? Have any advice ?

Comment: There's a race-condition in your code: `ngOnInit()` *may* run either before or after the `getJob()` HTTP request completes. You should use a `Subject<Job>` in your code and move `getJobTitle()` out of `JobService` (because `JobService` should not be stateful).

Comment: @Dai where i should keep the job related  method collection ?

Comment: Keep `getJob(id)` inside `JobService` but move `getJobTitle()` to your `JobDetailsComponent` - and have it use the `Subject<Job>`.

Comment: @Dai why i have to get job to take jobTitle from Api. I take it once. And i share the taken job between components. For example . JobDetails component will take jobTitle , but proposals component will take job requests which the requests is inside of Job.

Comment: @Dai is it true approach request to api for job second time?

Answer (score 1):

*The way you are trying to get it is not viable, since you try to get the value before the service resolves

Since this works asynchronously, if you want to run the service from the JobService and not from the Component, you can implement the * **async** and **await**. [MDNWeb_DOCS](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/funcion_asincrona)

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class JobService {

  jobUrl = 'http://localhost:5000/api/Job';
  job: Job;

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  getJob(id: number): Observable<Job> {
    return this.httpClient.get<Job>(this.jobUrl + '/' + id);
  }

  async getJobTitle() {

    await this.getJob(1).toPromise().then(x => this.job = x);
    // job object appears in jobservice object. It has initialized.
    console.log(this);

    // the object return undefined. Which service containing the job
    console.log(this.job);
    // setTimeout(() => console.log(this.job), 300);

    // also this is return undefined
    return this.job.title;
  }
}
```

**The component would be of the following way:**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { JobService } from '../job.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-jobdetails',
  templateUrl: './jobdetails.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./jobdetails.component.css']
})
export class JobdetailsComponent implements OnInit {

  jobTitle: any;

  constructor(private jobService: JobService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.jobService.getJobTitle().then(x => {
      this.jobTitle = x;
      console.log(this.jobTitle);
    });
  }
}
```

**It is advisable to declare the variables at the beginning of the class**

*Another way to do it is as follows:*

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class JobService {

  jobUrl = 'http://localhost:5000/api/Job';
  job: Job;

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  getJob(id: number): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient.get<Job>(this.jobUrl + '/' + id);
  }
}
```

**I leave you two ways to solve it from the Component**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { JobService } from '../job.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-jobdetails',
  templateUrl: './jobdetails.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./jobdetails.component.css']
})
export class JobdetailsComponent implements OnInit {

  jobTitle: any;

  constructor(private jobService: JobService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
     this.getJobTitle();
     this.getJobTitle2();
  }

  async getJobTitle() {
    await this.jobService.getJob(1).toPromise().then(x => this.jobTitle = x);
    console.log('getJobTitle', this.jobTitle, this.jobTitle.title);
  }

  getJobTitle2() {
    this.jobService.getJob(1).subscribe(x => {
      this.jobTitle = x;
      console.log('getJobTitle2', this.jobTitle, this.jobTitle.title);
    });
  }
}
```

I hope it Works for you

Comment: i don't want to request to api to api which it will bring me jobtitle. I get job from api once. Then i share the job between components. Maybe it is not true approach to request api to get jobtitle  which jobtitle already i have.

Comment: What I understand is that you want the service call to be made 1 time, and to be able to work with that response during the process, whether in 1 or several components. I have another option that can help you if that is the case, only that it depends on the initial execution. Comment on when you launch the first request to the service and how you can work with the same result without performing the service.